# JmsTemplate and CachingConnectionFactory

Tags: jboss, jms, spring-jms, jmstemplate

I'm finding some difficulties in trying to reduce the connection and session creation when sending messages to a Jboss Queue.

```
<bean name="jbmTemplate-${jbmQueue}" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate" lazy-init="true">
        <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true" />

    <!-- connection factory -->
    <property name="connectionFactory">
        <ref bean="jbmCachingConnectionFactory"/>
    </property>

    <property name="pubSubDomain">
        <value>false</value>
    </property>

    <property name="receiveTimeout">
        <value>${jmsReceiveTimeout}</value>
    </property>

</bean>
```

I'm using a JmsTemplate to send messages:

```
<bean id="jbmCachingConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
     <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="jbmConnectionFactory" />
</bean>
```

And the jbmConnectionFactory is defined as follow:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="jbmConnectionFactory" jndi-name="XAConnectionFactory"
        resource-ref="true" lookup-on-startup="false" proxy-interface="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory"
        cache="false">
    <jee:environment>
        java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
        java.naming.provider.url=${jbmURL}
        java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces
    </jee:environment>
</jee:jndi-lookup>
```

I'm using this piece of code to send messages to Jboss:

```
public void send(final Serializable payload, final String correlationId) {
    log.debug("payload: {}", payload);

    try {
        jmsQueueTemplate.send(destinationName, new MessageCreator() {
            public Message createMessage(Session session)
                    throws JMSException {
                ObjectMessage msg = session.createObjectMessage(payload);

                msg.setJMSType(payload.getClass().getCanonicalName());
                msg.setJMSCorrelationID(correlationId);

                return msg;
            }

        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Couldn't send message");
        throw new BlockingException(e);
    }
}
```

What I was trying to do by using the CachingConnectionFactory is to avoid creating and closing connections and sessions every message I send but as far as I can see, when using a JmsTemplate, no matter what type of connectionFactory I use, the connection and session will always be terminated:

```
finally {
            JmsUtils.closeSession(sessionToClose);
            ConnectionFactoryUtils.releaseConnection(conToClose, getConnectionFactory(), startConnection);
        }
```

Am I calling the wrong method? Is there something that I don't get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CachingConnectionFactory` returns a proxy (wrapper) for the connection which ignores the `close()`. Similarly, `session.close()` is intercepted and the session is put in the cache instead of actually closing it.

In fact, it **requires** the session to be "closed" so the session can be made available for the next use.

You may need to configure the cache size (it's only 1 by default; see the [javadocs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/jms/connection/CachingConnectionFactory.html)).

Comment: Hi @Gary, 
I've configured the cache size and increased it to 10 but the issue persists.
What I'm seeing is that when we are inside the "doGetTransactionalSession" method inside the execute:

`Session sessionToUse = ConnectionFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalSession(
     getConnectionFactory(), this.transactionalResourceFactory, startConnection);`

When he creates a new 

`
   resourceHolderToUse = new JmsResourceHolder(connectionFactory);
  `

He creates a JmsResourceHolder with no connection inside of it, hence he proceeds at creating it again.

Comment: Right, but since the `CachingConnectionFactory` only has one connection (it is a subclass of `SingleConnectionFactory`) he gets the same connection.

Comment: That's strange because I'm enqueuing messages and at the same time monitoring the connections on the receiving's machine and I'm seeing that everytime I enqueue a message the number of connections goes up (and comes back down after a while).
Is it working as intended?

Thanks

Comment: No; there must be something wrong with your configuration - there is only ever one connection from the CCF. You will get lots of information if you enable TRACE logging.

Comment: @Gary what would be the best approach in case the connection factory was managed by JCA in the container. I have a somehow similar concern with caching. Wouldn't the caching mechanism of JCA be redundant? I posted question(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28844426/springs-defaultmessagelistenercontainer-to-use-connection-factory-directly-from where I would appreciate your perspective. Thanks

Comment: It probably varies by provider; I don't have any specific general advice (otherwise I would have answered that question).

Comment: Oh, as always, you are right.

Here is the proof:
The first two are the connections (first being the one cached in the conn. factory, the second being the conn. being "created")
Shared JMS Connection: JBossConnection->ConnectionDelegate[5378289, ID=msa-rucdvy6i-1-i0l4ox6i-xs7g6u-111606a, SID=90]
Shared JMS Connection: JBossConnection->ConnectionDelegate[5378289, ID=msa-rucdvy6i-1-i0l4ox6i-xs7g6u-111606a, SID=90]

The same happens for the sessions.

Thanks again! :)

Then I guess maybe there's something on Jboss's side not closing the connections?